# Calculate pixels belonging to corners of rectangle after rotating image

Tags: python, geometry

I have seen some questions related to this topic, but I have been unable to get the results I was looking for even after following them, so I assume something about my math is off. Here's the scenario.

I have got an image that must be rotated by 90 degrees. At the same time, I have got the coordinates (x_min, y_min) and (x_max, y_max) of the corners of a rectangle that is drawn over a certain object in the image. Let's use the image below as an example, the rectangle being used here is defined by (4, 196) and (145, 269).

[image: Image with box]

My goal, then, is to rotate the image and do the same with the rectangle, assuring it keeps surrounding the target object.

First, I am rotating the image 90 degrees (clockwise) by using imutils.

```
90_rotated_image = imutils.rotate_bound(original_image, 90)
```

Then, I am calculating the new coordinates of the rectangle. For this, I need to know the point around which imutils rotates the image. I have tried a few combinations, including (0,0), but here I will assume it's the center of the image itself.

```
radians = math.radians(90)

h, w, c = original_image.shape

center_x = w/2
center_y = h/2

# Changes to solve the problem. Center of rotated image is now considered.

h_rotated, w_rotated, c = 90_rotated_image.shape

center_x_rotated = w_rotated/2
center_y_rotated = h_rotated/2

x_min_90 = center_x_rotated + math.cos(radians) * (x_min - center_x) - math.sin(radians) * (y_min - center_y)
y_min_90 = center_y_rotated + math.sin(radians) * (x_min - center_x) + math.cos(radians) * (y_min - center_y)

x_max_90 = center_x_rotated + math.cos(radians) * (x_max - center_x) - math.sin(radians) * (y_max - center_y)
y_max_90 = center_y_rotated + math.sin(radians) * (x_max - center_x) + math.cos(radians) * (y_max - center_y)
```

Finally, I draw the new rotated rectangle over the rotated image.

```
start_point = (x_min_90, y_min_90) 
end_point = (x_max_90, y_max_90)

image = cv2.rectangle(90_rotated_image, start_point, end_point, (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

Here's what I am getting.

[image: Rotated image with wrong box]

The question is: what's wrong here? Why won't the rectangle rotate properly and give me the intended result, simulated below.

[image: Intended result]

**EDIT:** To anyone stuck with the same problem, the solution to make the rotation work with rectangular images is quite simple. The center_x and center_y variables added to the result of the rotation (the multiplications involving sin and cos) have to be related to the center of the image post-rotation not pre-rotation as I had initially written into the code. The post has been updated to reflect the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, in general case center of image in global coordinates should look like this (I don't know exactly what is rotation center in your case):

```
center_x = min_x + w/2
center_y = min_y + h/2
```

Second: arguments of trigonometric function must be in **radians**, not degrees, so `math.cos(math.radians(degrees_angle))` and so on

Third: if before rotation, min_corner is **left bottom**, after rotation it becomes **right bottom** (or perhaps left top depending on your coordinate system orientation); same for max_corner. Also using rotation about some center, you have to add center coordinates at the end.

So min/max coordinates for rotated rectangle are:

```
x_min_90 = center_x + (y_min - center_y)
y_min_90 = center_y - (x_max - center_x)

x_max_90 = center_x + (y_max - center_y)
y_max_90 = center_y - (x_min - center_x)
```

[image]

For this example ABCD -> FGHI:

```
xmin = 2  ymin = 1
xmax = 8  ymax = 5

center_x = 2 + 3 = 5
center_y = 1 + 2 = 3

xmin90 = 5 + (1 - 3) = 3
y_min_90 = 3 - (8 - 5) = 0
x_max_90 = 5 + (5 - 3) = 7
y_max_90 = 3 - (2 - 5) = 6
```

Note:

1. I used mathematical coordinate system (OX right, OY to the top), if your OY axis goes down, then change orientation as needed.
2. I substituted cos and sin of 90 with 0 and 1. For other angles use cos and sin but **don't forget about radians**:

How to use formulas from question to get right result for angles 90,180,270 degrees:

```
x_a_90 = center_x + math.cos(radians) * (x_min - center_x) - math.sin(radians) * (y_min - center_y)
y_a_90 = center_y + math.sin(radians) * (x_min - center_x) + math.cos(radians) * (y_min - center_y)

x_b_90 = center_x + math.cos(radians) * (x_max - center_x) - math.sin(radians) * (y_max - center_y)
y_b_90 = center_y + math.sin(radians) * (x_max - center_x) + math.cos(radians) * (y_max - center_y)

x_min_90 = min(x_a_90, x_b_90)
x_max_90 = max(x_a_90, x_b_90)
y_min_90 = min(y_a_90, y_b_90)
y_max_90 = max(y_a_90, y_b_90)
```

Comment: Yeah, I left cos and sin in there because later I will do it for other angles. 

Anyway, sadly adding center to the equations and calculating the radians of the angle did not work. I have updated the original post with the new calculations I am using, so in case someone has extra insight on what is wrong, I'd be thankful!

Comment: Thanks! That rotation wouldn't work for my rectangle, though, as the one you show is being rotated around its own center. I need to rotate mine in relation to the image. I added a few example images of a local test I ran for clarification.

Comment: Your formulas are correct for rotation about any point - just put it's coordinates into center_x and center_y. But result is coordinates of new points, not max and min directly. Look at addition.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks again! For some reason, though, now it's working just fine for a 180-degree rotation, but still no luck for 90 and 180.

Comment: Oops. I meant 90 and 270!

Comment: You can put simple input values and check where mistake occurs

Comment: Ok, I figured out the problem is somehow related to the fact the image is not square. I ran the same code with an image whose height and width are equal, and the math is working. The box keeps track of the object through all increments on 90 degrees.

With the one that isn't square (the one posted in the question) the fact the proportions of the image change when it is rotated 90 or 270 degrees (with width becoming height and vice versa) messes up the calculations.